# BCNF decomposition process

Tags: database, relational, bcnf

What is the BCNF decomposition for these dependencies?

```
A->BCD
BC->DE
B->D
D->A
```

What is the process to get to the answer?

Answer (score 0):

We can first convert the relation `R` to 3NF and then to BCNF.

To convert a relation `R` and a set of functional dependencies(`FD's`) into `3NF` you can use ***Bernstein's Synthesis***. To apply Bernstein's Synthesis -

- **First** we make sure the given set of `FD's` is a **minimal cover**
- **Second** we take each `FD` and make it its own sub-schema.
- **Third** we try to combine those sub-schemas

***For example*** in your case:

R = {A,B,C,D,E}
FD's = {A->BCD,BC->DE,B->D,D->A}

**First** we check whether the `FD's` is a minimal cover (*singleton right-hand side , no extraneous left-hand side attribute, no redundant FD*)

- *Singleton RHS:* We write the FD's with singleton RHS. So now we have FD's as {A->B, A->C, A->D, BC->D, BC->E, B->D, D->A}
- *No extraneous LHS attribute:* We remove the extraneous LHS attribute `C` from FD `BC->D` and `BC->E`. So now we have FD's as {A->B, A->C, A->D, B->D, B->E, B->D, D->A}
- *No redundant FD's:* We remove the redundant dependencies. Now FD's are {A->B, A->C, B->D, B->E, D->A}

**Second** we make each `FD` its own sub-schema. So now we have -  (*the keys for each relation are in bold*)

R<sub>1</sub>={**A**,B}
R<sub>2</sub>={**A**,C}
R<sub>3</sub>={**B**,D}
R<sub>4</sub>={**B**,E}
R<sub>5</sub>={**D**,A}

**Third** we see if any of the sub-schemas can be combined. We see that **R<sub>1</sub>** and **R<sub>2</sub>** have the LHS so they can be combined. Similarly **R<sub>3</sub>** and **R<sub>4</sub>** can be combined. So now we have -

S<sub>1</sub> = {**A**,B,C}
S<sub>2</sub> = {**B**,D,E}
S<sub>3</sub> = {**D**,A}

This is in **3NF**. Now to check for **BCNF** we check if any of these relations (S<sub>1</sub>,S<sub>2</sub>,S<sub>3</sub>) violate the conditions of **BCNF** (*i.e. for **every** functional dependency `X->Y` the left hand side (`X`) **has to be** a **superkey***) . In this case none of these violate **BCNF** and hence it is also decomposed to **BCNF**.