# Decomposition to BCNF and set of super key

Tags: database, functional-dependencies, bcnf

So I have this set of relation

AB->CDEF

G->H,I

ABJ->K

C->L

How should I decompose this? I am so confused. Am I supposed to find the set of super key first?

Answer (score 2):

We can first convert the relation `R` to 3NF and then to BCNF.

To convert a relation `R` and a set of functional dependencies(`FD's`) into `3NF` you can use ***Bernstein's Synthesis***. To apply Bernstein's Synthesis -

- **First** we make sure the given set of `FD's` is a **minimal cover**
- **Second** we take each `FD` and make it its own sub-schema.
- **Third** we try to combine those sub-schemas

***For example*** in your case:

R = {A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L}
FD's = {AB->CDEF,G->HI,ABJ->K,C->L}

**First** we check whether the `FD's` is a minimal cover (*singleton right-hand side , no extraneous left-hand side attribute, no redundant FD*)

- *Singleton RHS:* We write the FD's with singleton RHS. So now we have FD's as {AB->C, AB->D, AB->E, AB->F, G->H, G->I, ABJ->K, C->L}
- *No extraneous LHS attribute:* We remove the extraneous LHS attribute if any. There are no extraneous LHS attributes here.
- *No redundant FD's:* We remove the redundant dependencies if any. Now FD's are {AB->C, AB->D, AB->E, AB->F, G->H, G->I, ABJ->K, C->L}

**Second** we make each `FD` its own sub-schema. So now we have -  (*the keys for each relation are in bold*)

R<sub>1</sub>={**A,B**,C}
R<sub>2</sub>={**A,B**,D}
R<sub>3</sub>={**A,B**,E}
R<sub>4</sub>={**A,B**,F}
R<sub>5</sub>={**G**,H}
R<sub>6</sub>={**G**,I}
R<sub>7</sub>={**A,B,J**,K}
R<sub>8</sub>={**C**,L}

**Third** we combine all sub-schemas with the same LHS. So now we have -

S<sub>1</sub> = {**A,B**,C,D,E,F}
S<sub>2</sub> = {**G**,H,I}
S<sub>3</sub> = {**A,B,J**,K}
S<sub>4</sub> = {**C**,L}

Since none of the above decomposed relations contain contain a key of **R**, we need to create an additional relation schema that contains attributes that form of a key of **R**. This is to ensure lossless join decomposition that preserves dependencies. So we add -

S<sub>5</sub> = {**A,B,G,J**}

*ABGJ is the key of the original relation R*

This is in **3NF**. Now to check for **BCNF** we check if any of these relations (S<sub>1</sub>,S<sub>2</sub>,S<sub>3</sub>,S<sub>4</sub>,S<sub>5</sub>) violate the conditions of **BCNF** (*i.e. for **every** functional dependency `X->Y` the left hand side (`X`) **has to be** a **superkey***) . In this case none of these violate **BCNF** and hence it is also decomposed to **BCNF**.

*Note -*  The importance of some of these steps may not be clear in this example. Have a look at other examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34294136/bcnf-decomposition-algorithm-explanation/34350122#34350122) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33889293/bcnf-decomposition-process/34371336#34371336).

Comment: The 3NF is incorrect. First, in S3, L should not be present (it is not determined by A B J). Then, you should add a relation with the key of the original relation (A B G J), since no decomposed relation contains it.

Comment: @Renzo Thanks for pointing that out. L in S3 was a typo but I completely forgot about adding another relation with the key of R since no decomposed relation contains it.