# Find keys and decompose it into BCNF

Tags: bcnf

I have this relation:

```
wiki(url,title,abstract,link,category_id,category,heading,heading_pos)
```

And the FD's are:

```
F = {
    url → title, abstract
    category_id → category
    url, heading_pos → heading
}
```

I need to find the keys and decompose into a set of Boyce-Codd normalized relations. I have tried to read related and similar questions but I'm unable to understand the given answers. Hope someone will help me with this assignment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming *'wiki'* as relation `R` and its attributes *url,title,..heading_pos* to be *A,B,...H* respectively.

We have,

R = {A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H}
FD's = {A->BC, E->F, AH->G}

The key here is **ADEH**.

We can first convert the relation `R` to 3NF and then to BCNF.

To convert a relation `R` and a set of functional dependencies(`FD's`) into `3NF` you can use ***Bernstein's Synthesis***. To apply Bernstein's Synthesis -

- **First** we make sure the given set of `FD's` is a **minimal cover**
- **Second** we take each `FD` and make it its own sub-schema.
- **Third** we try to combine those sub-schemas

***For example*** in your case:

**First** we check whether the `FD's` is a minimal cover (*singleton right-hand side , no extraneous left-hand side attribute, no redundant FD*)

- *Singleton RHS:* We write the FD's with singleton RHS. So now we have FD's as {A->B, A->C, E->F, AH->G}
- *No extraneous LHS attribute:* We remove the extraneous LHS attribute if any. There are no extraneous LHS attributes here.
- *No redundant FD's:* We remove the redundant dependencies if any. There are no redundant dependencies here.

**Second** we make each `FD` its own sub-schema. So now we have -  (*the keys for each relation are in bold*)

R<sub>1</sub>={**A**,B}
R<sub>2</sub>={**A**,C}
R<sub>3</sub>={**E**,F}
R<sub>4</sub>={**A,H**,G}

**Third** we combine all sub-schemas with the same LHS. So now we have -

S<sub>1</sub> = {**A**,B,C}
S<sub>2</sub> = {**E**,F}
S<sub>3</sub> = {**A,H**,G}

Since none of the above decomposed relations contain contain a key of **R**, we need to create an additional relation schema that contains attributes that form of a key of **R**. This is to ensure lossless join decomposition that preserves dependencies. So we add -

S<sub>4</sub> = {**A,D,E,H**}

This is in **3NF**. Now to check for **BCNF** we check if any of these relations (S<sub>1</sub>,S<sub>2</sub>,S<sub>3</sub>,S<sub>4</sub>) violate the conditions of **BCNF** (*i.e. for **every** functional dependency `X->Y` the left hand side (`X`) **has to be** a **superkey***) . In this case none of these violate **BCNF** and hence it is also decomposed to **BCNF**.

*Note -*  The importance of some of these steps may not be clear in this example. Have a look at other examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34294136/bcnf-decomposition-algorithm-explanation/34350122#34350122) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33889293/bcnf-decomposition-process/34371336#34371336).

Comment: I'm with you all the way to the third part until you add S4 = {A,D,E,H}. And thank you for your answer. I know that your answer is the correct answer.

Comment: Is it because A,D,E,H is the minimum candidate key?

Comment: Since none of the decomposed relations (S1,S2,S3) had A,D,E and H (attributes of the key) i.e. none of them individually contain all 4 attributes of the key we need to add another relation (S4) which do. This is to ensure [lossless decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossless-Join_Decomposition). Also none of S1,S2 or S3 had the attribute D. We can not just remove an attribute from a relation R after decomposition.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35664813/decomposition-to-bcnf-and-set-of-super-key/35665784) is another very similar question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think I understand it now.